# Is there any extra configuration for hosting MVC4 Web Api applications on loadbalancer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, load-balancing

We got Mvc4 Web application on server1 calling our Restfull Mvc4 Web Apis on server2 both hosted on IIS 7.5. This architechture works fine. When we put each application on loadbalanced servers the web application works fine however web api project doesnt run on the second server on the loadbalancer. We have just cloned the environments so they both have identical code and configuration but the servernames and mappings.

Is there any extra configuration for hosting MVC4 Web Api applications on loadbalancer?

has anybody actualy got MVC4 Web Api working on loadbalanced environment?

thanks,

Comment: yes. what is the exact error you encounter?

Comment: I dont get any response back when it goes to the second server, it just hangs. I will check the load balancer configuration and logs.

Comment: and can you call the api directly? skipping the load balancer

Comment: I have found the problem! The damn problem was our firewall blocking the web request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem! The damn problem was our firewall blocking the web request

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any extra configuration for hosting MVC4 Web Api applications on loadbalancer?

Not necessary if your Web API is stateless and you are not using any ASP.NET session. If you are using an ASP.NET session you might need to use an out-of-process session state instead of the default in-memory.

> Has anybody actualy got MVC4 Web Api working on loadbalanced environment?

Yes, I have.

Comment: Well we dont use session in Web Api. How is your load balancer configured, does it serve request in round robin logic